# When HttpWebRequest.Credentials should be used

Tags: .net, cookies, httpwebrequest, cookiecontainer

I tried to perform a `POST` using a `HttpWebRequest` instance to a web url that requires an authentication (an ASP.NET MV3 standart `[Authorize]` decorated action method with build-in membership system), but providing login and passowrd as `NetworkCredentials` in `HttpWebRequest` didn't do the trick.

I ended up using a global `CookieContainer` and two `HttpWebRequests`:

1. Set a request's `CookieContainer` to `globalCookieContainer`.
2. POST username and password to a logon URL. (after that step the container still reports the Cookie count is 0).
3. Create another `HttpWebRequest` instance and set the `globalCookieContainer` to request's `CoockieContainer`.
4. POST to a final url that requires authentication. For some reason, this time second request object provides the cookies as a part of a request and it goes through.

An entire "magic" of cookie management isn't discribed anywhere well (I really tried to search around).

We've got this scenario covered. But in what cases `HttpWebRequest.Credentials` should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest.Credentials` is meant to be used when the authentication is performed through one of the schemes in the [`AuthenticationSchemes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.authenticationschemes.aspx) enum. Among others, this includes Basic and Digest HTTP auth, NTLM and Kerberos.

That said, you can cook up your own custom authentication schemes by deriving from `NetworkCredential` on the client side and implementing [`IAuthenticationModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iauthenticationmodule.aspx) on the server side.

Comment: Jon, thank you very much. So authentication mode="forms" doesn't set the ASP.NET web site to Basic authentication? Those two, "Basic" and "forms" are not the same thing?